# Live countdown in django using keith wood countdown timer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django, jquery-countdown

Good day everyone, I am using keith wood countdown, How do i set the default countdown to (14 days)  countdown when after the user login, and the countdown will still be redundant even if the user logout or leave the page?

```
<div id="defaultCountdown"></div>
<script>
$(function () {
    var austDay = new Date();
    austDay = new Date(austDay.getFullYear() + 1, 1 - 1, 26);
    $('#defaultCountdown').countdown({until: austDay});
    $('#year').text(austDay.getFullYear());
});
</script>
```

this is my views.py

```
def profile(request):
    if request.method != 'POST':
        raise Http404('Only POSTs are allowed')
    try:
        m = User.objects.get(username=request.POST['username'])
        if m.password == request.POST['password']:
            aa = request.POST['username']
            request.session['member_id'] = m.id
            print(m.id)
            return render(request, 'profile.html')

    except User.DoesNotExist:
        messages.Warning(request, 'Incorrect Username or Password.')
    return render (request, "login.html")
```

Please help me guys,

Comment: So you want the 14 days countdown to be from the date the user logs in, for every individual useR?

Comment: yes mr@ Rory McCrossan

Comment: and still continue even the user leave the page or logout

Comment: Just save the datetime when the user logs in (or the expiry time which is the login time + 14 days) in the `User` model. Then you can always calculate how much time is left till the end of the countdown and either display it or pass it as a variable in your template that you can use in javascript.

Comment: Note that your login method (comparing `request.POST['password']` to `m.password`) is **very wrong**. It means you save passwords as plain text in your database! **Never do that**.

Comment: can you please show me how to do it? @dirkgroten

Comment: @justin Check out the Django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.hashers